# Append Multiprocessing output to a Data Frame in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-multiprocessing

I have two functions which I am running using multiprocessing in Python. I have given an example below (reduced the function code for simplicity). I want to append the output of both the functions into a single Data Frame and store into "df".

```
import multiprocessing 
  
def uttar_pradesh(): 
 
 
  up=pd.DataFrame({'date':'01-09-2020','time':'00:00:00','demand':6577,'state':"Uttar Pradesh"})
  
  return up
  
  
def andhra_pradesh(): 
  

   ap=pd.DataFrame({'date':'01-09-2020','time':'00:00:00','demand':3797,'state':"Andhra Pradesh"})
  
   return ap
  

  
if __name__ == "__main__": 
   
    df = []
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=uttar_pradesh )
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=andhra_pradesh) 
    
    df.append(p1)
    df.append(p2)
    
    p1.start() 
    p2.start() 

    p1.join() 
    p2.join() 
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `multiprocessing.Process()` won't give you any result values, it just runs functions in other processes.

Assuming you can rewrite your functions into the form

```
def get_state_data(state):
   return data_for_that_state
```

(and why couldn't you),

you can then use the higher-level `Pool` with `map` (or `imap` or `imap_unordered`):

```
states = ["uttar_pradesh", "andhra_pradesh"]
with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
   for result in p.map(get_state_data,  states):
       pass  # append the result data or do whatever with it
```

If you don't want to use Pool and map, you can also set up a `multiprocessing.Queue()` that you pass to the subprocesses and read it, but it's more work.

Comment: Getting this error- AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing.pool' has no attribute 'map'

Comment: Sorry, typo. Meant `p.map` (or `with ... as pool`), but corrected now.

Comment: Not Working, can you try with multiple functions